# Generate Websites with Apache Velocity

Tags: java, apache, web, velocity

I want to generate websites with Apache Velocity. The generated Website will contain e.g. the navigation from a website. The footer comes for example from a second Website and the Header from another Website.

I've understood how Velocity works but, how its possible to get e.g. the navigation from a site?

Answer (score 0):

There is a brief tutorial here on building web apps with velocity - https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/webapps.html

If you are looking to embed a webpage in another webpage you can use iFrames: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp